# How to specific conflict behavior while creating upload session using Graph sdk

Tags: java, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using Microsoft graph API to upload a large file. This is a 2 step process:

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Step1: Create an upload session

Step2: Upload bytes to upload session

In step1, while creating an upload session, I want to add conflict behavior. I am using Microsoft SDK for Java, In which **DriveItemUploadableProperties** this class does not have a field for conflict behavior.

I have done the following:

```
private DriveItemUploadableProperties createDriveItemUploadableProperties(AttachmentToUpload attachmentToUpload) {
    DriveItemUploadableProperties driveItemUploadableProperties = new DriveItemUploadableProperties();
    driveItemUploadableProperties.name = attachmentToUpload.getFileName();
    DefaultSerializer serializer = getDefaultSerializer();
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    JsonPrimitive conflictValue = new JsonPrimitive(attachmentToUpload.getConflictBehavior().toString());
    json.add("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", conflictValue);
    driveItemUploadableProperties.setRawObject(serializer, json);
    driveItemUploadableProperties.additionalDataManager().put("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", conflictValue);
    driveItemUploadableProperties.
    return driveItemUploadableProperties;
}
```

I have added conflict behavior in RawOvject and additionalDataManager as well, but it does not help.

Can anyone help me, how I'll add this property?

Even if I did not specify any conflict behavior, the default behavior is *"fail"*.

So, I uploaded the same file twice and I never receive any failure callback.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I have referred to this code [Java Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=java)

Comment: I see this too. The class doesn't have a property for it because it's not defined in the metadata. Using additionalDataManager **should** be the right approach, but the SDK isn't serializing that into the request body for some reason. I'm reporting it to the SDK team.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please share the issue link to track this?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/393

Comment: Even if I did not specify any conflict behavior, the default behavior is "fail".

So, I uploaded the same file twice and I never receive any failure callback.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Am I supposed to do some particular configuration regarding that?

Comment: My guess is that the docs are wrong about that being the default behavior. I'm seeing that it overwrites. Or maybe I don't understand what constitutes a "conflict" :).